# Indexing large geometries in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, gis, geojson

I have a dataset which contains a lot of polygons (bounding boxes of maps), which I want to index using Elasticsearch. All polygons are very simple (most of them rectangles), most of them are the size of towns and counties, but some are quite large and cover almost the whole world.

I cannot use a mapping with a high [`precision`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/mapping-geo-shape-type.html) setting for this data because of the geographic size of some objects, but I also do not want to lose precision for the smaller polygons.

Does Elasticsearch allow indexing of such a geographically heterogeneous dataset, and what would be the correct mapping options?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to look into [`distance_error_pct`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/geo-shape.html) as this is meant to have an error that is a percentage of the size of the shape, so very small for small shapes but bigger for bigger shapes.